# Run Navigation Stack with Maps from Kinect Fusion

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

i am a really newbie to the ROS system therefore if my question ist stupid or inapropriate please be kindly patient.

I have one Robot (er1) with Kinect as Sensor running under ROS and a Server with Kinect Fusion, which can generate maps. My Question is, is it possible to use Navigation Stack with the maps generated by KinFu?  The Tutorial says that Navigation Stack needs either LaserScan or PointCloud as the source for sensor information, but for me its not easy to convert datas from Kinect to LaserScan and PointCloud (and because of performance reasons).

Thanks for answers in advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200798/run-navigation-stack-with-maps-from-kinect-fusion/) by [kido](https://answers.ros.org/users/21331/kido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-12**:
What is the output from the KinFu?

**Comment by [kido](https://answers.ros.org/users/21331/kido/) on 2015-01-15**:
Hi David Lu, Voxelgrid. Kinfu uses the information from the depth-images generated by Kinect and then reconstruct them to voxelgrid. Sry that i didn't see your comment until today.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-15**:
Is that a specific ROS message?

**Comment by [kido](https://answers.ros.org/users/21331/kido/) on 2015-01-16**:
Hi David,maps are with datatype nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid, 1024*1024 Pixels (5 meter* 5meter)
You can see a [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/p8vjS2D.png) here, thx.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-04-04**:
Hi! I am also interested in using kinfu for 3D mapping and robot navigation. Please, could you provide some tips on how to integrate kinfu with ROS nav stack? Did you use KinfuLS-ROS-Wrapper from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl17)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Nav stack can accept OccupancyGrid messages as input. Usually they are input as "static maps" where they cover a large stationary area and are updated infrequently.

I don't know exactly how the Kinect Fusion works, but I could see it theoretically being used as input. However, I don't think it has been tried before.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kido](https://answers.ros.org/users/21331/kido/) on 2015-01-20**:
Thanks David, i'll take a try then make feedbacks here.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-20**:
Ok. Best of luck. Please hit the checkmark to close the question when you can.

**Comment by [kido](https://answers.ros.org/users/21331/kido/) on 2015-02-05**:
Thanks again to David. I tried and it works after setting the TF correctly. Neither Laserscan nor PointCloud are sufficient when i use the maps from KinFu as the Source for mapserver.